# Defining Training and Testing data instead of random split

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, data-science, data-science-studio

I would like the training and testing spilt to not be random instead it should be decided on the value of the column
for eg
training set = base_data[base_data['columnA']==0]
test set = base_data[base_data['columnA']==1]
i have tried to look up on multiple sites however i wasn't able to understand much since i'm new

Comment: Could you please provide a MRE? stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example